# jqGrid how do you loop through the grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a project that uses jquery's jqgrid.  How do I loop through the grid rows and get to a value?

somethign like

```
var rows = $(#mygrid).rows
foreach(row in rows)
    alert(row["firstName"])
```

I have even seen something like this, but no examples of what to do with it.

```
var rows = $('#grid').jqGrid('getCol','firstName');
```

Answer (score 15):

try this:

```
var rows = jQuery("#grid").getDataIDs();
 for(a=0;a<rows.length;a++)
 {
    row=jQuery("#grid").getRowData(rows[a]);
    row.colname1; row.colname2; 

 }
```